# Creating a new key for every new encryption? crypto Noode.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am developing a app that uses encryption, the source is viewable to the users, as its going to be open-source, I don't want they key to be publicly viewable, can I use a random number generator to generate a new key for each new encryption, then what would be a good secure method of distributing the key, from server to client, and vice versa?

Comment: That's not the key referenced in the snippet. That's the iv. You absolutely should be generating a new, random iv for each encryption. Re-using an iv can reveal repeated data in the beginning blocks of your messages across multiple encryptions. The iv is stored in the encrypted data, so does not need to be kept in your code or database.

Comment: Do I just create a random number generator for each new encryption, or is there a better method?

Comment: Use a cryptographically secure pseudo random generator from your language platform such as `window.crypto.getRandomValues` for javascript. Prepend the IV to the encrypted data so it will be available for decryption.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`crypto.randomBytes(size)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)? I'm not sure I understand your question properly. If you're creating a new key for each encryption, then you need to let the receiver know that new key. Do you have a secure way to distribute the key? Also, an IV is not to be confused with a key, because it is not supposed to be secret, but can be sent along with the ciphertext.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am asking for a secure way to randomly generate a new key for each new encryption, and securely distribute it.

Comment: Explain "distribute the key"? To what and how?

Comment: send it to from the  server to  client, and vice versa,  so the encrypted content can be decrypted.

Comment: DH exchange or equivalent.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @FlerrElectronics: Dan is referring to this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange